# command line arguments with multiple output files

Tags: python, file, command-line-arguments

If I want two output files from a command line argument, can I just specify a third argument? i.e.

```
            infile=sys.argv[1]
            outfile1=sys.argv[2]
            outfile2=sys.argv[3]
```

And then when i'm typing the command into terminal:

```
        python script.py infile.txt outfile1.txt outfield.txt
```

And get 2 output files?

Comment: yes, did you actually try it?

Comment: Does your script write to the files or do you want to save the displayed text in the console?

Comment: I just want to write to the files

Answer (score 0):

If you list all the "single" arguments first, you can use the last argument `sys.arg[4:]`, for example, to specify "the rest" of the arguments.